# Generic inside a generic kotlin

Tags: android, generics, mvvm, kotlin

I have some abstract class `BaseViewModel`, `BaseActivity`.

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<N> : ViewModel(){}
```

My purpose using **N** to pass as an interface into it, and when any `viewModel` extends to `BaseViewModel`, just pass its navigator into.

But I got a problem when write `BaseActivity`.

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding,V: BaseViewModel<???>> : AppCompatActivity() {}
```

what it should be?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<N> : ViewModel(){}

abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding,V: BaseViewModel<Test>> : AppCompatActivity() {}

interface Test
```

You can make it even more protected, if you extend from base interface:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<N:BaseTest> : ViewModel(){}

abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding,V: BaseViewModel<Test>> : AppCompatActivity() {}

interface Test:BaseTest

interface BaseTest
```

In that case, if you interface doesn't inherit generic's parent class, compiler will give you an error of compilation.